# creating relation between range value and changable value

Tags: integration, limits

Hi I have stuck into a problem, which I have shared here. 
I am unable to think, which mathematical formula should I follow. If you can suggest me something will be a great help.
Thanks

start value = 'sv'.

end value =  'ev'.

____|__________________|_____

```
    sv <--------------------> ep
              (range)
```

'x' = changable value

'y' = dependent value on x with max value and min value

when

```
 x = sv, y = min value

 x = ev, y = max value
```

relation between x and y

Comment: This question has uncountably many possible answers. If you know nothing about the relationship between $x$ and $y$, then any function is equally likely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic relationship is "affine"

$$y=ax+b$$

with $a=\dfrac{y_{min}-y_{max}}{ep-sv}$ (the slope $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$).

and $b=\dfrac{ep * y_{max}-sv * y_{min}}{ep-sv}$ (chosen such that, for example, if $x=sv$ then $y=y_{min}.$)